# Kivy-simple drawing app

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

I created a simple application for drawing. I got  this error:
 "pythonw.exe has stopped working"
I do not understand why it shows me this error, I'd love to help :)

my kivy code:

```py
from kivy.app import App
# kivy.require("1.8.0")
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Line
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition

class Painter(Widget):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        with self.canvas:
            touch.ud["line"] = Line(points=(touch.x,touch.y))

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        touch.ud["line"].points += [touch.x,touch.y]


class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass

class AnotherScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenManegmant(ScreenManager):
    pass

presention = Builder.load_file("main1.kv")



class SimpleKivy(App):
    def build(self):
        return presention

if __name__ =="__main__":
    SimpleKivy().run()
```

my kv.language code(called main1.kv):

```py
#: import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition

ScreenManegmant:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    MainScreen:
    AnotherScreen:

<MainScreen>:
    name: "main"
    Button:
        on_release: app.root.current= "other"
        text: "next"
        font_size: 50



<AnotherScreen>:
    name: "other"

    FloatLayout:
        Painter
        Button:
            on_release: app.root.current= "main"
            text: "back"
            font_size: 25
            color: 0,1,0,1
            size_hint: 0.3,0.2
            pos_hint: {"left":1,"up":1}
```

someone know how can i fix that?

Answer (score 0):

This app works for me. Tho I get error if I started drawing in the transition, because the touch will allready be on the move before the `touch.ud["line"]` is created. To fix that you can check if the key exists in the `on_touch_move` method, and then create it.

Also try running it from cmd instead of idle.

```py
class Painter(Widget):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        with self.canvas:
            touch.ud["line"] = Line(points=(touch.x,touch.y))

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        if "line" not in touch.ud:
            touch.ud["line"] = Line(points=(touch.x,touch.y))
        touch.ud["line"].points += [touch.x,touch.y]
```

Comment: I do not think it's because when I created a very simple app who used ScreenManagment I got the same error. i wrote the app in the next answer.

Comment: @ShaharBitan did you run it from cmd, and not from idle?

Comment: now I got the same error , but just after i click on the first button.

Comment: what can be the problem?

Comment: @ShaharBitan well its not the code. I will test this on my win pc in a moment.

Comment: i understand its not the code, its my pc, but what can be the problem?

Comment: @ShaharBitan your kivy installation

Comment: then I need to download kivy again? What do you suggest?

Comment: @ShaharBitan yes I would completely remove kivy, and install it again

Comment: from where can i install kivy in the best way?

Comment: @ShaharBitan here using pip https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html#install-win-dist